# SSRS show sales data per week days

Tags: sql, reporting-services, pivot

I need to create a report which would show sales by department by week day in the following format:

```
Department  Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun 
Dep1
Dep2
Dep3
```

Currently data is in list format and my current query is

```
SELECT
sales_reporting_view.department_name
,sales_reporting_view.created_date
,sales_reporting_view.sales_spti
FROM
sales_reporting_view
```

I have looked around and one of the solutions is to use Pivot function but I failed to make it work for my example as I'm quiet new to SSRS. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could PIVOT the SQL query and then just create a simple SSRS report, or if you want to keep the pivoting/formatting in SSRS you should use a Matrix.

For the Matrix use the Department as your "Rows" input. Use FORMAT(created_date, "ddd") as your "Columns" input.  And use sales_spti as your "Data" input.

You can sort the columns using DAYOFWEEK(created_date), which would order them Monday(1) through Sunday(7).  See [SSRS Date functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337153%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for further info.

Comment: I tried Matrix with Format as a Column group and it gives me exactly what I need.

Comment: How I would be able to sort the days from Mon - Sun if I used FORMAT?

Comment: Yes.  Set Sorting in the Grouping and Sorting Properties to sort by DAYOFWEEK(created_date)

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. I had to use Weekday(Fields!created_date.Value,2) as Dayofweek wasn't available on SSRS 2008 R2 and week started with Sunday